# Find first and last trip with same source-destination by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with source, dest, and time of the trip. I want to find list of all the sources that had same destination for the first and last trip of the day. Table looks like below:

```
Source  Dest    Trip_Time
1   2   2/1/2019 6:00
2   3   2/1/2019 7:00
4   2   2/1/2019 7:00
1   3   2/1/2019 8:00
2   1   2/1/2019 9:00
3   1   2/1/2019 9:00
4   1   2/1/2019 9:00
1   4   2/1/2019 15:00
2   1   2/1/2019 17:30
3   5   2/1/2019 17:30
4   5   2/1/2019 17:30
2   3   2/1/2019 19:45
3   1   2/1/2019 19:45
5   2   2/1/2019 19:45
1   4   2/2/2019 17:00
1   3   2/2/2019 21:00
```

I have figured out a query to get what I wanted, but I was wondering if there is more optimal way of achieving the result, especially the one that'll work with millions of rows.

````
select source, max(first_trip) ft, max(last_trip) lt from 
(select source, case when (a.max) = 1 then (dest) end as first_trip,
case when (a.min) = 1 then (dest) end as last_trip from (select source, dest, time_trip, 
Row_Number() Over (partition by source order by time_trip desc) as max,
Row_Number() Over (partition by source order by time_trip asc)  as min  from trips) a 
where a.max = 1 or a.min = 1) b
group by b.source) c where ft = lt```

Expected result: 
caller  fc  lc
2   3   3
3   1   1
5   2   2
````

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `first_value()` and `last_value()`.  Date functions are notoriously dependent on the database, but you need to extract the date from the `trip_time`.  The following illustrates the idea but the date function could differ on your database:

```
select distinct source, cast(trip_time as date)
from (select t.*,
             first_value(dest) over (partition by source, cast(trip_time as date) order by trip_time asc) as first_dest,
             first_value(dest) over (partition by source, cast(trip_time as date) order by trip_time desc) as last_dest
      from trips t
     ) t
where first_dest = last_dest;
```

Comment: Using postgreSQL